# split image on the basis of color

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

[image]

[image]

I have obtained an image after applying k-means with clusters = 3. Now I want to obtain 3 separate images on the basis of colours obtained after k-means.
For example, consider the attached image. Now I need
one image such that it contains only the blue square.
One having the letter v and one with just the background
Is there any possible way to do that using OpenCV and python.

Comment: So make 2 additional clones. In one, make everything that isn't white, black and save. In another, make everything that isn't blue, black and so on.

Comment: @MarkSetchell this is just an example image, I don't know the colours I will receive

Comment: Ok, pick random pixels till you have 3 different ones, or start at top-left and iterate through till you have your 3 different colours.

Comment: can you post few more images for testing

Comment: Can't you use the label image rather than the quantized-color one ? That would avoid "reverse engineering" the colors.

Comment: I added one more image as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general and simplest way to do it is using the three unique gray colors for each region. (Although I could find more than three gray levels in the above image, maybe due to variation as a result of compression of imgur. Though, at the end of the day, k-means should give exactly three BGR values)

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
unique = np.unique(gray)
c1, c2, c3 = unique[0], unique[1], unique[2]

mask1 = np.zeros_like(gray)
mask1[gray == c1] = 255

mask2 = np.zeros_like(gray)
mask2[gray == c2] = 255

mask3 = np.zeros_like(gray)
mask3[mask3 == c3] = 255
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by calculating the histogram of the image. 
The below plot shows the peaks of the image.

[image: plot]

From this, you can threshold the colors. The code and result:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("inputs/hist.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
colors = np.where(hist>5000)
img_number = 0
for color in colors[0]:
    print(color)
    split_image = img.copy()
    split_image[np.where(gray != color)] = 0
    cv2.imwrite(str(img_number)+".jpg",split_image)
    img_number+=1
plt.hist(gray.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.savefig('plt')
plt.show()
```

Results:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: This will fail when two colors or more have the same luminance.

Comment: @YvesDaoust can we use HSV color space to solve the issue?

Comment: There is no need to switch to HSV. Keep RGB. (And in fact, working with the Label image would be much better.)