# Split image in N images, where N is the number of colors appearing on it

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to split an image depending on the colors it contains.

My previous steps have been to simplify it to just 3 colors using the KMeans algorithm that `Sklearn` offers and I get a result like the following image.

[image]

Now I need to split it in 3 images one for each color. And obtain something similar to this (I have done it with photoshop).

*The examples are done in black and white because really if I can do the division, I no longer need the colors. But I would do just as well with 3 color images.*

Mask 1:

[image]

Mask 2:

[image]

Mask 3:

[image]

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735574/split-image-on-the-basis-of-color), but I can't achieve my goal.

I have thought about separating by channels, but I think it is wrong.

```
# set green and red channels to 0
blue_img[:, :, 1] = 0
blue_img[:, :, 2] = 0
# set blue and red channels to 0
green_img[:, :, 0] = 0
green_img[:, :, 2] = 0
# set blue and green channels to 0
red_img[:, :, 0] = 0
red_img[:, :, 1] = 0
```

I think the key is in my kmeans algorithm, because with it I obtain `labels` and `centroids` of my colors but I really don't know how to do it, and I can't find anybody doing it.

My KMeans algorithm is:

```
def get_colors(img, number_of_colors, show_chart, show_segmented_img):
    
    modified_image = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)
    
    myKMeans = KMeans(n_clusters = number_of_colors)
    
    labels = myKMeans.fit_predict(modified_image)
    
    counts = Counter(labels)
    
    centroids = myKMeans.cluster_centers_
    
    ordered_colors = [centroids[i] for i in counts.keys()]
    
    hex_colors = [RGB2HEX(ordered_colors[i]) for i in counts.keys()]
    
    rgb_colors = [ordered_colors[i] for i in counts.keys()]
    
    if (show_chart):
        plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
        plt.pie(counts.values(), labels = hex_colors, colors = hex_colors)
        plt.show()

    if (show_segmented_img):
        centroids = np.uint8(centroids)
        segmented_data = centroids[labels.flatten()]
        segmented_image = segmented_data.reshape(img.shape)
        segmented_image = cv2.cvtColor(segmented_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imwrite('segmentedImg.png', segmented_image)

    return hex_colors, rgb_colors
```

can somebdoy help me please?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT: From Hihikomori's answer.**

From Hihikomori's answer, I understand that I should do the following, this is based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735574/split-image-on-the-basis-of-color) that I linked before, but the problem is that I get 3 black masks without any contour so I thought that this would not suit me.

```
def get_colors(img, number_of_colors, show_chart, show_segmented_img):
    
    modified_image = img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 3)
    
    myKMeans = KMeans(n_clusters = number_of_colors)
    
    labels = myKMeans.fit_predict(modified_image)
    
    counts = Counter(labels)
    
    centroids = myKMeans.cluster_centers_
    
    ordered_colors = [centroids[i] for i in counts.keys()]
    
    hex_colors = [RGB2HEX(ordered_colors[i]) for i in counts.keys()]
    
    rgb_colors = [ordered_colors[i] for i in counts.keys()]

    # TRYING THE ASNWER
    color1, color2,color3 = rgb_colors
    first_color_indices = np.where(np.all(img == color1, axis=-1))
    second_color_indices = np.where(np.all(img == color2, axis=-1))
    third_color_indices = np.where(np.all(img == color3, axis=-1))

    img1 = np.zeros_like(img)
    img1[first_color_indices]=color1

    img2 = np.zeros_like(img)
    img2[second_color_indices]=color2

    img3 = np.zeros_like(img)
    img3[third_color_indices]=color3

    print('***')
    cv2_imshow(img1)
    print('***')
    cv2_imshow(img2)
    print('***')
    cv2_imshow(img3)
    print('***')
    
    if (show_chart):
        plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6))
        plt.pie(counts.values(), labels = hex_colors, colors = hex_colors)
        plt.show()

    if (show_segmented_img):
        centroids = np.uint8(centroids)
        segmented_data = centroids[labels.flatten()]
        segmented_image = segmented_data.reshape(img.shape)
        segmented_image = cv2.cvtColor(segmented_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imwrite('segmentedImg.png', segmented_image)

    return hex_colors, rgb_colors
```

Comment: If each mask represents a different color, why do the masks have some regions in common?

Comment: Because I mistake it when I did the example with photoshop, sorry

Comment: Have you considered converting image to HLS or HSV matrix? Hue stand for color, like red green blue
`cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the unique colours in your image with `np.unique()` and then iterate over them setting each pixel to either white or black depending whether it is equal to that colour or not:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('cheese.png')

# Reshape into a tall column of pixels, each with 3 RGB pixels and get unique rows (colours)
colours  = np.unique(im.reshape(-1,3), axis=0)

# Iterate over the colours we found
for i,colour in enumerate(colours):
    print(f'DEBUG: colour {i}: {colour}')
    res = np.where((im==colour).all(axis=-1),255,0)
    cv2.imwrite(f'colour-{i}.png', res)
```

**Sample Output**

```
DEBUG: colour 0: [0 0 0]
DEBUG: colour 1: [0 141 196]
DEBUG: colour 2: [1 102 133]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
color1 = (0,0,160)
color2 = (0,160,160)
color3 = (160,160,160)
img = np.zeros((640,480,3),np.uint8)

img[100:200,100:200] = color1
img[150:250,150:250] = color2
img[200:300,200:300] = color3

first_color_indices = np.where(np.all(img == color1,axis=-1))
second_color_indices = np.where(np.all(img == color2,axis=-1))
third_color_indices = np.where(np.all(img == color3,axis=-1))

img1 = np.zeros_like(img)
img1[first_color_indices]=color1

img2 = np.zeros_like(img)
img2[second_color_indices]=color2

img3 = np.zeros_like(img)
img3[third_color_indices]=color3

cv2.imshow('origin', img)
cv2.imshow('img1', img1)
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
cv2.imshow('img3', img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks! But I only get 3 black masks with this code. I have edited my question in case you see the bug (probably silly).