# Separating overlaying colors in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

Let's say I have a picture with two colors, but both their colors are overlapping.

Object A is a star, and object B is a rectangle with a star-like hole. They overlap each other.

[image]

Is there a way of separating the objects? Kinda like finding the intersection and summing up to their "pure" standards?

[image]
[image]

I see two ways of doing this: via shape recognition or via color. Don't know which way would be smarter.

First I tried to separate the colors via histogram in grayscale, such as in [BATspock's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735574/split-image-on-the-basis-of-color) question

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("origin.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
colors = np.where(hist>25000)

img_number = 0

for color in colors[0]:
    print(color)
    split_image = img.copy()
    split_image[np.where(gray != color)] = 0
    cv2.imwrite(str(img_number)+".jpg",split_image)
    img_number+=1

plt.hist(gray.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.savefig('plt')
plt.show()
```

But no success in getting the color of that intersection due to very low Histogram values.

I tried using the example present [here](http://opencv-tutorials-hub.blogspot.com/2015/10/splitting-colour-images-into-RGB-channels-split-merge-opencv-code-channels.pushback-src-mv.html), although it renders the same effect I desire, the example just refers to color splitting in RGB. Is there anything similar to this output but choosing the colors instead? Maybe feature recognition? Watershed? I'm lost.

[image]

Comment: When I analyzed you input image there are 4 different rgb scales: 1- red(255,14,23) 2- white(255,255,255) 3- white+yellow(255,255,2) 4- yellow + red(255,45,2). so why you just dont mask it according to the scale filter

Comment: Did you try `pyrMeanShiftFiltering()`?